# Is there a limit for showing RewardedAd of Admob?

Tags: admob, adsense

Is there a limit or caution from Google for using **RewardedAd** for limited time?

So, in my app if I let my user to watch rewarded ad as many times he/she wants, will **Google** consider that as a **invalid traffic** which can lead to deactivation of account?

Answer (score 2):

No there is no such limitation for rewarded ads. But wherever you implement the rewarded ads, it should provide a good experience to the end-user, it should should provide value to the user with reward, like some feature will be unlocked.
Before clicking the link or button user should know what reward will it get.